# how to configure multiple validations for formGroup in Angular 5 application

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am working on Angular reactive form validation. My current structure have only validation.required and I need additional validations to setup but struggling to do so.
I need validation for
  - minLength,
  - email and
  - postcode

I am creating form dynamically from json data.

### formGroup validation service

```
@Injectable()
export class QuestionControlService {
constructor() { }

toFormGroup(questions: QuestionBase<any>[] ) {
let group: any = {};

questions.forEach(question => {
  group[question.key] = question.required ? new FormControl(question.value || '', Validators.required)
                                          : new FormControl(question.value || '');
   // need help here for forms.
  });
    return new FormGroup(group);
 }
}
```

### base question component

```
export class QuestionBase<T>{

key: string;
label: string;
required: boolean;
minLength:number;
order: number;
controlType: string;

constructor(options: {

    key?: string,
    label?: string,
    required?: boolean,
    minLength?:number,
    order?: number,
    controlType?: string,
  } = {}) {

  this.key = options.key || '';
  this.label = options.label || '';
  this.required = !!options.required;
  this.minLength = options.minLength;
  this.order = options.order === undefined ? 1 : options.order;
  this.controlType = options.controlType || '';
  }
 }
```

also I need to custom validation error according to its type, currently have only for required! as in following code

### template

```
<div [ngSwitch]="question.controlType">

       <div *ngSwitchCase="'textbox'"> <small>textbox</small>
           <div class="form-group">
               <input *ngSwitchCase="'textbox'" 
                      [formControlName]="question.key" 
                      [id]="question.key" 
                      [type]="question.type"
                      [(ngModel)]="question.value" 
                      (keyup.enter)="onChangeValue($event, previousValue, responseId, question.key, 'textbox'); previousValue = question.value" 
                      (blur)="onChangeValue($event,  previousValue, responseId, question.key, 'textbox'); previousValue = question.value"
                      (focus)="previousValue=question.value"
                      >
                      <span></span>
           </div>
       </div>
  <div class="errorMessage" *ngIf="!isValid">{{question.label}} is required</div> 
 </div>
```

Comment: Why are you having `formControlName` and `[(ngModel)]` in same `input` element? You can remove `[(ngModel)]` as you are using reactive-form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FormControl` accepts either a single validator, or an array of validators (`ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[]`). You can pass multiple validators as an array.

```
class FormControl extends AbstractControl {
  constructor(formState: any = null, 
              validatorOrOpts?: ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[] | AbstractControlOptions | null, 
              asyncValidator?: AsyncValidatorFn | AsyncValidatorFn[] | null)
```

---

```
new FormControl(question.value || '', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)])
```

Here is an [example code from angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#built-in-validators) showing multiple error messages:

```
<input id="name" class="form-control"
       formControlName="name" required >

<div *ngIf="name.invalid && (name.dirty || name.touched)"
     class="alert alert-danger">

  <div *ngIf="name.errors.required">
    Name is required.
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="name.errors.minlength">
    Name must be at least 4 characters long.
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="name.errors.forbiddenName">
    Name cannot be Bob.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how I modified

```
@Injectable()
export class QuestionControlService {
constructor() { }

toFormGroup(questions: QuestionBase<any>[] ) {
   let group: any = {};

questions.forEach(question => {

  var validations: ValidatorFn[] = [];

  if(question.required) {
    validations.push(Validators.required)
  }

  if(question.minLength)
  {
    validations.push(Validators.minLength(question.minLength))
  }

  group[question.key] = new FormControl(question.value || '', validations);                                                                                    
 });
   return new FormGroup(group);
 }
}
```

### mapping json data to Text object

```
 if(questionElementType=="textbox")
 {       

   let _textBox = new TextboxQuestion({
     consultationId: questionsList[key].consultationId,
     questionId: questionsList[key].questionId,
     questionElementType: questionsList[key].questionElementType[0].title,        
     questionType: questionsList[key].questionType,
     title:questionsList[key].title,
     displayId: questionsList[key].displayId,
     key: questionsList[key].questionId, 
     label: questionsList[key].title,
     value: questionsList[key].answer.length<=0? null : questionsList[key].answer[0].answerValue,
     required: true,
     minLength:8,
     order: 5
    }); 

    this.mappedQuestions.push(_textBox);

 }
```